# Flask route template

Tags: python, html, flask

When i route my flask app i received bad request. But i don't understand why i can't rendering my html template.

This is my app route code:

```
@app.rout('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main_page():
    return render_template('sign.html')

@app.route('/sign', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def SignResource():
    data = {
    "amount": request.form['amount'],
    "payway": request.form['payway'],
    "description": request.form['description']
    }
```

And this is my templates form:

```
<form action = "http://localhost:5000/sign" method = "post">
          <div class="pay_info">
              <input type="text", name='amount', value="12.34">
              <input list="currency_list" name="payway" autofocus>
              <datalist id="currency_list"  >
                  <option value="RUB">
                  <option value="USD">
                  <option value="EUR">
             </datalist>
          <div class='description_text'>
              <input type="text", name='description', value='Test description'>
         </div>
         <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

In template I write data on html form and then I parsed it in "/sign" route.
But when i try rendering my html i got code 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling of route is wrong here in below code:

```
@app.rout('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main_page():
    return render_template('sign.html')
```

Correct it:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main_page():
    return render_template('sign.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main_page():
    return render_template('sign.html')

@app.route('/sign', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def SignResource():
    data = {
    "amount": request.form['amount'],
    "payway": request.form['payway'],
    "description": request.form['description']
    }
    return "ok"
```

the function name rout is not right and need a return for request